# New partition shows up as loop device

Tags: partitioning, mount

I just installed a new SSD in my system, created a ext4 partition and mounted it.
It shows up as mounted, but when I enter `df -h`, it shows up as a loop device:

mount: `/dev/sde1 on /mnt/new type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)`

df -h: `/dev/loop5            62G   53M   59G   1% /mnt/new`

Notice the size of only 62G for a 2TB drive.

What is going on here?

Comment: Please add the output of sudo gdisk -l /dev/sde  to your original posting.  Partitions may be made any size, and you may have more of them than one.